# Does AWS Lambda support WAR packages when deploying a Java web application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, aws-lambda, war

We're trying to migrate our J2EE web application to Amazon Lambda .  The web application is currently deployed on a Wildfly 11 server.  After reading Amazon's docs -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html , I don't see anything about support for the WAR package.  Their ZIP package looks somewhat similar, but has structural differences.

Is there a way to deploy my web application (WAR file) to lambda, and if not, is there a simple way to convert it to the structure AWS Lambda is expecting?

Comment: Not every EE application would make sense as a Lambda.  Can you describe a bit more about your app?  Lambda doesn't support the `.war` format but there may be other ways of doing it depending on your app.

Comment: It's a pretty standard MVC application that connects to a database.  Uses Spring for MVC, Hibernate for ORM.  It connects to a memcache server for session management.  Is this the kind of things you were wanting to know?

Comment: I feel that this would not be a good candidate for an AWS Lambda.  Lambda's run for a maximum of 5 minutes and then are done.  I use them for things like REST services or other one-shot type event driven use cases.  But I wouldn't put anything UI based on Lambda other than a service that the UI uses.  You might be better off looking at something like Elastic Beanstalk for something like this.

Comment: Ok, but why are UI-based things bad candidates?  None of the requests currently take anything near 5 minutes (they shoudl all execute in a matter of seconds) and the ability to scale seems like a really useful thing.

Comment: I guess there are a few things.  The first is that there is a single entry point to a Lambda.  You'll need to rewrite your calls to execute that.  So, using the API gateway, you'll be able to map, say, `/index.html` to call the Lambda method.  Now your HTML will get `/css/main.css` or something.  So now you need another Lambda for that or map it some other way.  Not to mention having to reconstitute your session over and over again.  Lambda's are really aimed at microservice architectures, not full blown UI's.

Comment: Ok, thx for this explanation.  It is helpful.